# Some FA icons are displayed in FF, Chrome and Safari, but no browser displays them all

Tags: html, css, font-awesome-5

I'm using a template from Pixelarity (https://pixelarity.com/ethereal) where they implemented font awesome v4. Since I'd like to use 'brands' as well, I needed to hook up v5.

After trying to combine the FA v5 CSS with the template's CSS it broke somehow (I'm not a CSS-Pro).

In particular, there is a grid of six circles and each of them contains an icon. Firefox displays five of them, Chrome displays three of them and Safari only shows one icon.
There are several smaller icons (social media) on that site as well and only Firefox is able to display them properly.

I really ran out of ideas and I hope some of you is able to help me.

Imho, it is not helpful right now to provide all of my code since it is visible through developer tools in browsers as well, am I right? Please let me know if anybody needs specific lines out of my *.css or *.html

Thank you very much in advance.

All the best from Germany,
Marcel

EDIT:

I did as suggested. Tried to troubleshoot and reproduce where the mistake might be using my local apache (Mamp on a mac). I'm afraid I still don't have any explanation, but at least I found kind of a pattern in the browser's behavior.

With my `fontawesome.css` containing the following lines, it works

- like a charm in firefox. All icons are displayed properly
- partly in safari. Only icons out of `Font Awesome 5 Brands` are displayed
- partly in chrome. Only icons out of `Font Awesome 5 Brands` and `Font Awesome 5 Free (solid)` are displayed

```
  .sr-only {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px; }

.sr-only-focusable:active, .sr-only-focusable:focus {
  clip: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  position: static;
  width: auto; }
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.svg#fontawesome") format("svg"); }

.fab {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands';
  font-weight: 400;  
@font-face 
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.svg#fontawesome") format("svg"); }

.far {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 400; 
@font-face 
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.svg#fontawesome") format("svg"); }

.fas {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900; 
@font-face 
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: url("../fonts/fa-regular");
  src: url("../fonts/fa-solid-900.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/fa-solid-900.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/fa-solid-900.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/fa-solid-900.svg#fontawesome") format("svg"); }
```

If I now delete the `.fas`, `.far` and `.fab`, so the code looks like the following, it works

- partly in firefox. Only icons out of `Font Awesome 5 Brands` and `Font Awesome 5 Free (solid)` are displayed.
- like a charm in safari. All icons are displayed properly.
- partly in chrome. Only icons out of `Font Awesome 5 Brands` and `Font Awesome 5 Free (solid)` are displayed.

```
.sr-only {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px; }

.sr-only-focusable:active, .sr-only-focusable:focus {
  clip: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  position: static;
  width: auto; }
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.svg#fontawesome") format("svg"); }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.svg#fontawesome") format("svg"); }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: url("../fonts/fa-regular");
  src: url("../fonts/fa-solid-900.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/fa-solid-900.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/fa-solid-900.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/fa-solid-900.svg#fontawesome") format("svg"); }
```

I followed the instructions from fontawesome.com for including the whole font into the page's *.css and also triple checked the paths to the fonts.

Adding a bracket here and chrome works, deleting a bracket there and safari works...
I'm totally stuck and have no idea what to do, since I've no clue why three different browsers behave in such a different manner.

Comment: _"it is not helpful right now to provide all of my code since it is visible through developer tools"_ ... well that's not true because your site link will change/update/move and then this question will be of no help to people in the future. And currently it doesn't even load lol

Comment: Okay, I see. But my main.css contains of ~3.7k, my fontawesome.css of ~4.2k and my index.html of ~800 lines. Is there a smart way to offer these files to you here?

Comment: Try to isolate the problem in a small code sample that's reproducible (you can include libraries like FontAwesome as a cdn reference). Often when doing this you will solve the problem on your own, this is part of the debugging process. And if you still can't solve then come here and post what you have tried.

Comment: No errors in your various browser's developer consoles? It's able to load the font files correctly, and shows no CSS errors?

Comment: Maybe you can paste your code into something like codepen, plnkr or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that somebody will be as stupid as I am, but nevertheless I let you know about the mistake in my code.

Font Awesome consists of three fonts which are free to use.

- FA Brands
- FA Regular
- FA Solid

In the *.css they are called with `@font-face` and inside of that they are separated by `font-family: <Font Name>`.

If you look at my previous code, every font (brands, regular and solid) is called separatly with an individual `@font-face`-argument. And that's where the magic happens!
Since `FA Regular` and `FA Solid` are both part of the family called `Font Awesome 5 Free` several browsers seem to struggle with finding the correct font if there are two different fonts declared to be in the same family. The reason FA Brands was displayed properly is that its family is called `Font Awesome 5 Brands`.

Long story short. Out of

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.svg#fontawesome") format("svg"); }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.svg#fontawesome") format("svg"); }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: url("../fonts/fa-regular");
  src: url("../fonts/fa-solid-900.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/fa-solid-900.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/fa-solid-900.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/fa-solid-900.svg#fontawesome") format("svg"); }
```

I made

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/fa-brands-400.svg#fontawesome") format("svg"); }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400, 900;
  src: url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.svg#fontawesome") format("svg");

  src: url("../fonts/fa-solid-900.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/fa-solid-900.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/fa-solid-900.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/fa-solid-900.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/fa-solid-900.svg#fontawesome") format("svg"); }
```

And now it works like a charm for all browsers.

Thanks to all your advice and help!

Have a good one,
Marcel

Answer (score 0):

Since we're discussing our mistakes here, I'd like to share the problem-solution I had with newbies like me.

First, I added FA using a CDN link after I created a free kit on their website:

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/xxxxxx.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Since I'm using a free version, not all the icons can be displayed in my browsers. As I figured out later, you can only use a specific icon style that was given to you in a free version. I.e., if

```
<i class="fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-left"></i>
```

was provided in solid style, I should use it that way and can't change it to, let's say, "fa-light".

In my code, I mixed up **"far"** (stands for regular) and **"fas"** (solid) not knowing what the difference between them was.

Long story short, the following code was displaying icons in Safari but not in Chrome:

```
<i class="far fa-circle-chevron-left"></i>
```

After fixing the style, icons started displaying in both browsers correctly:

```
<i class="fas fa-circle-chevron-left"></i>
```